# how to change the pseudo time trajectory direction?

Tags: seurat, single-cell, monocle

[Monocle](http://cole-trapnell-lab.github.io/monocle-release/) is a comprehensive bioinformatics package which has the function to run the pseudo-time trajectory and changes in direction.

I wish to replicate this analysis. Like in the figure I would like the right side to be the pseudostar.

Thank you so much for your guys help[image]

Comment: Thanks for the figure. Its a standard PCA with time described by a colour gradient. IMO it looks fairly easy to do outside Monocle, just my opinion though.